# Does CodeBlocks corrupt Dev studio projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, codeblocks

I am at a new company and they use 2012 Dev Studio express.  I would like to use CodeBlocks as the limitations on Express are frustrating.

Assuming I use the MS compiler does CodeBlocks corrupt anything in the Dev studio project structure?  Other developers will be working on the same code (via GIT) so I need to make sure that there are no side effects which might effect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there should be no major side effects, maybe a IDE specifics if you're not careful. My group has used Dev (and Visual) Studio Express and CodeBlocks on the same project and it was perfectly fine. 
So I doubt there will be any corruption.